# How do I prevent proper nouns from being converted to lowercase by a bst file in LaTex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, capitalization

My bibliography contains some items like this:

> R. K. Sawyer, “Improvisation and the creative process: Dewey, collingwood, and the aesthetics of spontaneity,”

The problem is that the proper nouns in the title, such as "Collingwood", are getting converted to lowercase when they should not. It should appear like this:

> R. K. Sawyer, “Improvisation and the creative process: Dewey, Collingwood, and the aesthetics of spontaneity,”

Another example also removes necessary punctuation:

> G. Deleuze, “Lecture transcripts on spinozas concept of affect,”

This should be:

> G. Deleuze, “Lecture transcripts on Spinoza's concept of affect,”

I have checked that they are correct in my bibtex file. I'm using `IEEEtranS.bst`, which is what is introducing these problems (I guess). Advice?

It seems like bad design that I should have to further edit my bib file to add braces or something, and it is at least inconvenient given that the bib file is generated with Zotero. I do not want to have to re-edit the bib file every time I re-export the bib file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your style uses the BibTeX function `change.case$`. So if you don't want to change your bib file you have to change the `bst` file. Maybe another package/style is more suitable. I recommend `biblatex` (as often).

Comment: Is biblatex smart enough to avoid clobbering the titles? Can you suggest an alternative bst (IEEEtranS.bst was specified by the conference), or can you give the specific alteration I need to make to the bst file? That is, what should I replace change.case$ with?

Comment: `biblatex` is more than smart enough ;-) -- However I don't know your requirements ans so it's difficult to suggest any other style. Sorry. -- I will write a small answer.

Comment: Either you apply `change.case$` or not; there's no way to distinguish persons' names from other words: BibTeX doesn't know English, it just follows its rules.

Comment: I believe it's considered good practice to encase words in title fields that should not be converted to lower-case in a pair of curly braces: `{Collingwood}`, `{Spinoza's}`, etc. Regarding the missing apostrophe in the second example: do check, if you don't mind, if you have an ordinary "single apostrophe" or a "smart" apostrophe in your input file; if it's the latter, LaTeX/BibTeX is going to ignore it. :-(

Comment: The apostrophe in "Spinoza's" is the apostrophe-quote, #039. Littering my bibliographic information with brackets is really poor, though it could be said that Zotero should implement a solution to export to bibtex with such brackets. Maybe the problem of knowing English or not could be solved by storing all entries in lower case except for proper nouns and then have the bst capitalize according to style, rather than vice versa. Which solution is going to be the least painful, I wonder.

Comment: @renick - You wrote, "Littering my bibliographic information with brackets is really poor". I guess I would take exception to the notion that encasing proper names -- Collingwood, Spinoza, ... -- that occur in the `title` field in curly braces represents "littering". Providing such mark-up is a one-time-only operation, and it sets up the bib entries so that they generate the correct output whether or not "sentence style" is in effect.

Answer (score 3):

I save a copy of `IEEEtranS.bst` in my working directory and renamed it to `myIEEEtrans.bst`.

My test file is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mwebib.bib}
@ARTICLE{article-full,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System},
   journal = {G-Animal's Journal},
   year = 1986,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   pages = "73+",
   month = jul,
   note = "This is a full ARTICLE entry",
}

@BOOK{book-full,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Seminumerical Algorithms",
   volume = 2,
   series = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   address = "Reading, Massachusetts",
   edition = "Second",
   month = "10~" # jan,
   year = "1981",
   note = "This is a full BOOK entry",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{article-full} and \cite{book-full}

\bibliographystyle{myIEEEtranS}
\bibliography{mwebib}
\end{document}
```

Inside of `myIEEEtrans.bst` I changed the function `format.articles.title` as follows (line 1442):

```
FUNCTION {format.article.title}
{ title duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      "t" write$ 
%      "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { quote.close 'this.status.quote :=
      is.last.char.not.punct
        { punct.std 'this.status.punct := }
        { punct.no 'this.status.punct := }
      if$
      select.language
      "``" swap$ *
      cap.status.std
    }
  if$
}
```

After this I got the following output:

> [image]